# Pushing a Mutable Array into the TableView

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to push a mutable array into the UITableView.But my UITableView doesn't get update when i press the button. The tableview remains empty... I have already created NSLog of tableitems and their count. The value shown in the output are correct. Not sure what the error is.

The ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{
    UILabel *lbl;
    NSTimer *stopTimer;
    NSDate *startDate;
    BOOL running,lap;
    UIButton *bttn;
    NSMutableArray *tableItems;
    NSString *timeString;
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *bttn;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tableItems;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *timeString;

-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)resetPressed:(id)sender;

-(void)updateTimer;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize lbl,bttn,tableItems,timeString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    lbl.text = @"00.00.00.000";
    running = FALSE;
    lap = FALSE;
    startDate = [NSDate date];
    tableItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)startPressed:(id)sender{
    if(!running){
        running = TRUE;
        lap = TRUE;
        [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [bttn setTitle:@"Lap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        if (stopTimer == nil) {
            stopTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                         target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:YES];
        }
    }else{
        running = FALSE;
        lap = FALSE;
        [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [bttn setTitle:@"Restart" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [stopTimer invalidate];
        stopTimer = nil;
    }

}
-(void)updateTimer{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    lbl.text = timeString;
}

-(IBAction)resetPressed:(id)sender{
    if (!lap) {
        [stopTimer invalidate];
        stopTimer = nil;
        startDate = [NSDate date];
        lbl.text = @"00.00.00.000";
        running = FALSE;
    }
    else{
        [tableItems addObject:timeString];
        NSLog(@"%@",tableItems);
        NSLog(@"%i",tableItems.count);
    }

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return tableItems.count;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Step 1:Check whether if we can reuse a cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //Step2: If there are no new cells to reuse,create a new one
    if(cell ==  nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    //Step 3: Set the cell text content
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Step 4: Return the row
    return cell;

}
@end
```

Have linked the datasource and delegate to the tableview in the interface builder. Not sure what my error is...

Comment: How and where do you load the table?

Comment: [tableItems addObject:timeString];

Comment: What problem are you having? You never stated the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding object to `tableItems` array will not load the table.

You need to call `[tableView reloadData];`

Also, for this you will need to create outlet of the table in your interface file.

Comment: where do u add the [tableView reloadData];?

Comment: After adding the object to array